# discretizing surface integral using nodal DG method

Tags: finite-element, discontinuous-galerkin

I am currently learning nodal DG methods, primarily through the book by Warburton, and am a bit confused on how to handle surface integrals using straight edged elements.  On page 187 (and on page 214) of Warburton's book, we have

$$
\int_{\partial E_{k}} \mathbf{n} \cdot f_{h} \ell_{i}^{k}(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}.
$$

Recall that $f_{h} = \sum_{j=1}^{N} f_{j}(x,t)\ell_{j}(\mathbf{x})$ and $\ell_{i}(\mathbf{x})$ is our basis function, and so,

$$
\int_{\partial E_{k}} \mathbf{n} \cdot f_{h} \ell_{i}^{k}(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} = \int_{\partial E_{k}} \mathbf{n} \cdot \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{N} f_{j}(x,t)\ell_{j}(\mathbf{x}) \right]\ell_{i}^{k}(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}\\
= \sum_{j=1}^{N} \mathbf{n} \cdot f_{j}(x,t) \int_{\partial E_{k}} \ell{j}(\mathbf{x}) \ell_{i}(\mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}\\
= \sum_{j=1}^{N} \mathbf{n} \cdot f_{j}(x,t) M^{k}_{ij}.
$$
Now, to discretize the surface mass matrix, we must use a quadrature rule on each face (since I am working in 2D it's a line integral along each edge).  With that said, since we have an orthonormal basis, we can compute the mass matrix analytically.  For volume integrals, Warburton shows that $M^{k}_{ij} =  (\mathcal{V} \mathcal{V}^{T})^{-1} J,$ where $J$ is the metric Jacobian.  So intuitively, the same would be for the mass matrix, however, the Vandermonde matrix, $\mathcal{V}$ would be constructed so its on the local face points $(r,s)$, where $(r,s) \in [-1,1]$. Now, looking at their code (https://github.com/tcew/nodal-dg/blob/master/Codes1.1/CFD2D/CurvedEulerRHS2D.m), we see that the surface integral term has no surface mass matrix.  There is an inverse mass matrix applied to the numerical flux but it is the one from the time-derivative.  I was curious if someone could point out why there is no surface mass matrix in their formulation.

Comment: I assume that $\ell_j$ is a basis function, but it won't hurt if you clarify your notation.

Comment: For what I understand you I think that you want to interpolate your flux using the same basis functions, that's why you get a mass matrix. But, that's not the only way to solve that integral. You could, for example, use numerical integration and evaluate the function in a discrete set of points. Also, you could assume that the function is constant in your element and use the centroid value.

Comment: I edited my post to specify what l_{j}(x) is.  I understand you want to numerically integrate the mass matrix at the quadrature points, however, what I don't understand is why it seems to be 1 in this case (specifically line 56 of the code).  In their example code, they interpolate the f_{j} and n to the edges using Vf (Vf = Vg*inv(V), where Vg is the Vandermonde matrix evaluated at the quadrature points). However, why would that remove the need to directly evaluate the mass matrix as the edges?  Sorry if I am completely missing something.  Wouldnt you interpolate f_{j}, n, and M to the edges?

Comment: You don't need a mass matrix for surface terms. That appears only if you interpolate $f$. I haven't taken a look at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2D your volume part consists of a double integral, whereas the surface part is a standard line integral. Generally this is described with tensorial notations.

If you consider the **Cartesian case**, the volume part results in a mass matrix similar to

$M_{\Omega}\equiv  \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}$,

whereas the surface part results in a mass matrix similar to

$M_{\partial \Omega}^{\xi}  \equiv \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{I}_1\\
 M_{\partial \Omega}^{\eta} \equiv \mathbf{I}_1 \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}$.

Here $\mathbf{I}_1$ is the identity matrix.

If you invert the volume part and apply it on $\xi$-faces you will get something like

$=\left( \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}\right)^{-1}(\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{I}_1) \\ =  (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1} \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1})   (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{I}_1) \\ = (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1}  \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ) \otimes   (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}^{-1} \mathbf{I}_1)\\ = \mathbf{I}_{\text{1}} \otimes   \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}^{-1}$

or similar on $\eta$-faces

$=\left( \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}\right)^{-1}(\mathbf{I}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{M}_1) \\ =  (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1} \otimes \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1})   (\mathbf{I}_{\text{1}} \otimes \mathbf{M}_1) \\ = (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}} ^{-1}  \mathbf{I}_{\text{1}} ) \otimes   (\mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}^{-1} \mathbf{M}_1)\\ = \mathbf{M}_{\text{1}}^{-1} \otimes   \mathbf{I}_{\text{1}}.$

**Summerizing**: I think you are missing the fact, that both mass matrices (volume and surface) cancel, resulting in a 1D inverse mass matrix. Note that numerical fluxes on $\eta$-faces are projected into the volume in $\xi$-direction, whereas fluxes on $\xi$-faces are projected into the volume in $\eta$-direction.

Regards